# AttributeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'make_initializable_iterator'

Tags: python

I receive: 'AttributeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'make_initializable_iterator''
I am using:
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

```py
train_data, train_data_infer=_get_training_data(FLAGS)
iter_train = train_data.make_initializable_iterator()
iter_train_infer=train_data_infer.make_initializable_iterator()
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! You should edit your question adding more information: tf version, SO version, cuda version, and so on. By the way, formatting code inside your question

Comment: tf version is 2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Method you are looking for is `tf.compat.v1.data.make_initializable_iterator(dataset)`

As long as you use `tf.compat.v1`, it should be enough to replace

```
iter_train_infer=train_data_infer.make_initializable_iterator()
```

with

```
iter_train_infer = tf.data.make_initializable_iterator(train_data_infer)
```

If you get `make_initializable_iterator is not supported when eager execution is enabled`, then add `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` at startup of your application.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'disable_eager_execution'

Comment: I suppose, it was moved to compat library. Please try this:
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
and let me know if it helps, I'll update my answer in that case

Comment: yup looks like it  --> https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/disable_eager_execution. Thanks!